# SBT can't resolve Play source jars (play

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

#### The setup

I've recently set up an Artifactory to protect our project from jar infection and my Play scala project is now having some issues resolving dependencies.

My `~/.sbt/repositories` file:

```
[repositories]
  local
  artifactory-ivy: https://build-server/artifactory/repos-ivy, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  artifactory-ivy-sbt: https://build-server/artifactory/repos-ivy, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  artifactory-maven: https://build-server/artifactory/repo
```

and my `~/.sbtconfig` file:

```
SBT_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true"
```

With those set SBT resolves most dependencies using the artifactory, except for those bundled inside Plays local repo (which they change the `${ivy.home}` property to set to a repo they bundle inside the installation zip file.

#### The problem

Except that SBT now fails to resolve `play_2.10-test-sources.jar`, `play_2.10-sources.jar` and `play_2.10.pom` with the following error message:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.0!play_2.10.jar(src)
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.0!play_2.10.jar(src)
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.0!play_2.10.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

When I look at the ivy logging I see that the only place Ivy tried to look for these jars and the pom is in the local:

```
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.0!play_2.10.jar(src) (0ms)
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/michael/Projects/gds/ier/frontend/scripts/bin/play-2.2.0/repository/local/com.typesafe.play/play_2.10/2.2.0/srcs/play_2.10-test-sources.jar
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.0!play_2.10.jar(src) (1ms)
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/michael/Projects/gds/ier/frontend/scripts/bin/play-2.2.0/repository/local/com.typesafe.play/play_2.10/2.2.0/srcs/play_2.10-sources.jar
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.0!play_2.10.pom (0ms)
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/michael/Projects/gds/ier/frontend/scripts/bin/play-2.2.0/repository/local/com.typesafe.play/play_2.10/2.2.0/poms/play_2.10.pom
```

I've tried to replicate with a fresh project but I can't seem to get it to cause the same issue. I'm really not sure why Play is looking for these files as it has the `play_2.10.jar` and should work without the rest.

Comment: have you add `resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"` in your project/plugins.sbt ?

Comment: I'm intentionally trying to avoid using resolvers other than our own artifactory. The proxy repo `artifactory-maven: https://build-server/artifactory/repo` mirrors Typesafes releases as well as other common maven ones like Maven central. 

The real issue here was that it doesn't try the others, only tries `local`

Comment: Have you download the `"http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"` to your local dir ? Or you may want to proxy typesafe repo.

Comment: As i mentioned above the `artifactory-maven` repo mirrors the Typesafe releases as a proxy repo. Not sure you understand what the issue here is.

Answer (score 0):

First, try putting the `repositories` file in the `~/.sbt/0.13` directory.  Starting with 0.13, sbt expects to find files in the subdirectory named by the version.

If that doesn't work, try explicitly specifying the `repositories` file by adding this to your `SBT_OPTS`:

```
-Dsbt.repository.config="~/.sbt/0.13/repositories"
```

I had to set this property for my builds to find plugins when using our own repo.  Since Play is a plugin, it may be hitting the same issue.  The only difference in my case is that I didn't try putting the `repositories` file in `~/.sbt/0.13`.  I put it in `$sbt_home/conf` and added the above property.

Comment: according to the sbt output, the `repositories` already works!